# Compiling AutoDock-GPU on windows from source- Can't include the path for the CL headers

Tags: makefile, build, g++, opencl, nvidia

I am trying to compile AutoDock Vina GPU from source. I am using cygwin and running the make command and it leads to an error saying that `#include "CL\opencl.h: No such file or directory`. I have the Nvidia toolkit installed and it is in the path `C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\Vina\project\GPU_SOURCE\AutoDock-GPU-develop`.

The makefile also has the line `LIB_OPENCL = -lOpenCL`. After reading many forums, I learned that I need to include the path to the OpenCL headers from the toolkit, but CFLAGS did not end up working. However, after changing the line from the makefile to `LIB_OPENCL = -I'/cygdrive/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/include'  -lOpenCL`, I no longer get the "no such file or directory" error. I get a new error saying that `lOpenCL` can't be found. Excluding `-lOpenCL` from the makefile causes it to make many undefined references.

How exactly should I structure this to properly compile and build?

Comment: Does is say `lOpenCL` can't be found?  Or does it say `OpenCL` can't be found?  Please cut/paste the command that make prints before you get this error so we can see it.  Also it would be helpful if you cut/paste the makefile rule that contains the command that fails.

Comment: Thank you, but I got it working by changing a line in the make file from `LIB_OPENCL = -lOpenCL` to `LIB_OPENCL = -I'/cygdrive/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/include'  -L'/cygdrive/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/lib/x64' -lOpenCL `. Now I have another issue saying that __cxa_atexit could not be located in the dynamic link library autodock_gpu_128wi.exe